# Is it possible to convert a std.builtin.TypeInfo.Error back to its error value?

Tags: zig

The struct `std.builtin.TypeInfo.Error` only contains a `name` field. And since no `@nameToError` function exists, I don't see a way to convert this to it's error value.

In version 0.6 of zig that struct has a `value` field, which holds the number to instantiate the error via `@intToError`. But that no longer exists.

Am I overseeing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the answer via the zig issue tracker.

```
@field(MyErrorSet, "errorName")
```

can be used to get the error value.